# VBA Dropdown not auto run

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I have vba code for dropdown where I put in Sheet 5. The dropdown information is located in Sheet 4 where I set the module as setupDV_2. The range that I made for dropdown information is not manually key in (the figure coming from formula). The VBA is work only if I click run button but it not run automatically. However, if I key-in manually the figure (instead of using formula), then the VBA work. This is my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Range
Set r = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("K8:K1000"))
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    Call setupDV_2
End If
End Sub
```

this is my code for SetupDV_2

```
Sub setupDV_2()
Dim rSource As Range, rDV_2 As Range, r  As Range, csString As String
Dim c As Collection
Set rSource = Sheets("4").Range("K8:K1000")
Set rDV_2 = Sheets("5").Range("C8:C1000")
Set c = New Collection
csString = ""
On Error Resume Next
For Each r In rSource
    v = r.Value
    If v <> "" Then
        c.Add v, CStr(v)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            If csString = "" Then
                csString = v
            Else
                csString = csString & "," & v
            End If
        Else
            Err.Number = 0
        End If
    End If
Next r
On Error GoTo 0
'MsgBox csString
With rDV_2.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=csString
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = False
End With
End Sub
```

What I want is, even each cell from the Range("K8:K1000")" is coming from formula, the dropdown work automatically instead of manually click RUN button. I suspect it due to Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range).

Comment: A cell value being modified by a formula does not trigger the `Worksheet_Change`. But it triggers `Worksheet_Calculate` event...

Comment: What is the formula in `K8:K1000`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 the formula is =IF(AND(ISTEXT(C9),ISNUMBER(D9)),C9&D9,"")

Comment: Then, you may use `Change` event for `range("C8:C1000")`, or if you want learning, try using `Calculate` event. Create a `Static` variable to keep the initial range (to be observed) and then compare that Data with the existing one after `Calculation`. If a difference exists then, run the sub and exist the event code. I can show you a piece of code, if interested...

Comment: Please help to assist if i still want to use cell K (which contain formula). since it combination from Cell C & Cell D. @FaneDuru

Comment: Anyhow, you cannot keep the working way! `Calculate` event does not have a `Target` parameter. OK, I will post an answer, at least, for didactic use...

Answer (score 0):

Please, copy the next code in the sheet code module where the K:K range to be monitored exists:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Static dict As New Scripting.Dictionary 'static variable, keeping the reference values
   Dim lastR As Long: lastR = Me.Range("K" & Me.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last cell on K:K.
   Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Me.Range("K8:K" & lastR) ' to be dynamic if values will be added (lastR)
   Dim boolFound As Boolean
   
   If dict.count = 0 Then loadDictionary dict, rng: Exit Sub 'load ot first time
   Dim i As Long
   For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
        If dict.Exists(rng.cells(i).address) Then
            If dict(rng.cells(i).address) <> rng.cells(i).value Then 'value has been modified
                Debug.Print dict(rng.cells(i).address), rng.cells(i).address, rng.cells(i).value 'only to see the different values...
                dict(rng.cells(i).address) = rng.cells(i).value 'add it to the reference dictionary range
                If Not boolFound Then Call setupDV_2: boolFound = True
            End If
        Else
            dict.Add rng.cells(i).address, rng.cells(i).value ' add the new key to the dictionary
            If Not boolFound Then Call setupDV_2: boolFound = True
        End If
   Next i
End Sub

Sub loadDictionary(dict As Scripting.Dictionary, rng As Range)
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
    dict(rng.cells(i).address) = rng.cells(i).value
  Next i
End Sub
```

It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'. In fact, I will also post a piece of code, able to automatically to add the respective reference:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  Application.vbE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
End Sub
```

Please, run this last code first time and then copy the above code. First time a change appear in K:K, it will only lead the reference dictionary. Starting from the second change it will call the necessary sub, when something was changed or a new value has been added to that column.

Comment: @Wafee89 Didn't you find some time to test the above event code? If tested, didn't it work as you need? Is it anything you did not understand and needed to be clarified?